# Jenkins pipeline mark inner node stage as a failure

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am running my build on Linux node. During the build, one of the stages is running part of code on a different node. When this internal part fails I see whole build status as a failure but the stage which contains execution on the second node is marked as a success (btw. all stages are marked as success). Example:

```
node('labelA') {
    stage('stage A') {  }
    stage('stage B') {  
        node('label B') {
            stage('stage C') {  }
        }
    }
}
```

When the above pipeline fails in stage C then all stages are marked as a success but the whole build is marked as a failure. How can I change it so the correct failing stage is marked? 
I already tried with: `currentBuild = 'FAILURE'` and `sh 'exit 1'` but it did not help.

Comment: have you tried setting `currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'` in the inner stage?

Comment: Yes - I tried. It didn't help.

Comment: Another approach is `sh "exit 1"` if this doesn't work, then update this information in your question so that someone else can help and won't recommend same approach.

Comment: I found a problem - when one stage is in another then it will not mark correctly.